# Linux Fultter desktop - unable to run app from compiled executable, flutter run works

Tags: linux, flutter, crash, desktop

Flutter doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.19.0-2.0.pre.193, on Linux, locale pl_PL.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.19.0-2.0.pre.193 at /home/michal/android/flutter
    • Framework revision fed18fc433 (3 hours ago), 2020-05-29 03:43:01 -0400
    • Engine revision 17737e6fd4
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-11.0.dev 6489a0c68d)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    29.0.0-rc2)
    • Android SDK at /home/michal/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.0-rc2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/michal/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: /home/michal/android/studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 9.0.1-12
    • cmake version 3.16.3
    • ninja version 1.10.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /home/michal/android/studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.1

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 64 • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 10
      (API 29) (emulator)
    • Linux                        • Linux         • linux-x64      • Linux
    • Web Server                   • web-server    • web-javascript • Flutter
      Tools
    • Chrome                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google
      Chrome 84.0.4147.21 dev

• No issues found!
```

My app compiles succesfully and I am able to run it without any issues with `flutter run -d Linux`. However, that does not work when I try to run directly compiled executable, in this case I'm getting error message:

```
embedder.cc (781): 'FlutterEngineInitialize' returned 'kInvalidArguments'. Not running in AOT mode but could not resolve the kernel binary.
Failed to start Flutter engine: error 2
Failed to create window.
```

Command to compile:
`flutter build linux`

Any suggestion how to get it running as standalone app?

Comment: what is the command you used for generating the executable?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: from the [documentation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Desktop-shells#building) 

Building
In addition to linking the Flutter library, your application will need to bundle your Flutter assets (as created by flutter build bundle). On Windows and Linux you will also need the ICU data from the Flutter engine (look for icudtl.dat under the bin/cache/artifacts/engine directory in your Flutter tree).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to run the executable that's at the top level of the build output. You need to instead run the copy in the `bundle` subdirectory of the build directory, which has all the supporting files in the correct relative locations.

Once Linux is further along, details of how to use what's in the build directory will be documented somewhere.

> Any suggestion how to get it running as standalone app?

The `bundle` directory as a whole is the standalone app. If you mean having everything in a single executable file without any supporting files needed, that's not possible.

Comment: You are right. I missed that, because on Windows there's no 'bundle' directory, so I wrongly assumed Linux executable is top level too